# Add Markers dynamically to layer

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

i have a state with layers and points

```
this.state={layers: {"layer_1": [{lat: '', long: ''}, ...]}}

Object.keys(this.state.layers).map((layerName, i)=>
  <Overlay key={`marker-${i}`} name={layerName} checked>
    (markers for layer_1...)
```

But every time a new point is added to state a new Overlay is created.

How can i use the existent Overlay to add new points?

Answer (score 0):

try using the layerName as key

```
Object.keys(this.state.layers).map((layerName, i)=>
    <Overlay key={layerName} name={layerName} checked>
    //   (markers for layer_1...)
```